# Failed to create Azure Cosmos DB account

Tags: azure

Have been trying to create an Azure Cosmos DB account for almost whole day, but kept getting failure for below reason. When would it be possible to have this service back to normal and usable?

```
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
        {
            "code": "ServiceUnavailable",
            "message": "Sorry, we are currently experiencing high demand in this region, and cannot fulfill your request at this time. We work continuously to bring more and more capacity online, and encourage you to try again shortly. Please do not hesitate to contact us via Azure support at any time or for any reason using this link http://aka.ms/azuresupport.
```

Comment: That sounds like a question for Azure support. You could try creating your deployment in a different region or contact Azure support as suggested in the error message: http://aka.ms/azuresupport.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are not Azure support.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the high demand in certain Azure regions due to Covid-19. The ability to create certain services is being throttled in some regions and some account types.

You can try other regions or wait.

Comment: Any official sources on this?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/our-commitment-to-customers-and-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/